# How can I run a curl script with a variable for grep in a WEB page?

Tags: macos, curl, command-line

I am running from my terminal the command for curl for a page to grep some text, but I want to run it for a series of pages
I want to automate the process from command line and not run the process for every existing page.
We assume that we know the last page (e.g 197) from the WEB page
I do this time many times, every day

I want to repeat for x=1,2,3......  a certain number, with a for loop from command line

`curl https://somedomain/?page=x | grep TEXTREQUIRED

i want to return:

page(s) [1, 5, 13, 100] - TEXTREQUIRED found

if the string exists in the above pages

Answer (score 0, accepted):

my personal rule of thumb is "never write anything remotely complex in bash", use a better scripting language for that, and MacOS actually ships with a better scripting language: php-cli

a fitting php-cli script could be something like:

```
#!/usr/bin/env php
<?php
if ($argc !== 5) {
    die("usage: {$argv[0]} 'http://base_url.com?page=' 'search term' start_number end_number\n");
}
$start = (int) $argv[3];
$end = (int) $argv[4];
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($ch, array(CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1, CURLOPT_ENCODING => ''));
for ($i = $argv[3]; $i <= $argv[4]; ++$i) {
    $url = $argv[1] . $i;
    echo "\r{$url}: "; // with \r only matches will get it's own line
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    if (false !== stripos(curl_exec($ch), $argv[2])) {
        echo "MATCH!\n"; // \n gives the match it's own line.
    }
}
```

if you save it as `scanner.php` and give it `chmod +x scanner.php` , then you can run from the terminal like

```
$ ./scanner.php
usage: ./scanner.php 'http://base_url.com?page=' 'search term' start_number end_number

$ ./scanner.php 'http://example.org?page=' 'example' 5 10
http://example.org?page=5: MATCH!
http://example.org?page=6: MATCH!
http://example.org?page=7: MATCH!
http://example.org?page=8: MATCH!
http://example.org?page=9: MATCH!
http://example.org?page=10: MATCH!
```

- and non-match lines are not given their own line, they are just overwritten with the next number.

Answer (score 2):

How about this:

```
n=25
REGEX="foo"
for x in {1..$n}
do
    if curl -L 'https://somedomain.com/?page='$x 2>/dev/null | grep -q "$REGEX"
    then
        echo "$x"
    fi
done
```